# Check if a variable string contains only certain characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure with an input variable that I would like check if it only contains numbers or commas, and if it doesn't, throw an error. Ex's of the what the variable string could be:

```
@inputvariable = 489
@inputvariable = 489,504
```

I'm trying to do something like:

```
IF (@inputvariable NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%' OR @inputvariable NOT LIKE '%,%')
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('@inputvariable can only contain numbers and commas', 18, 1)
    RETURN
END
```

If the variable contains at least 1 number or 1 comma, it doesn't through an error even if there are "invalid" characters. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `THROW` is probably better than `RAISERROR`

Answer (score 3):

You may use the pattern `[^0-9,]`:

```sql
IF (@inputvariable LIKE '%[^0-9,]%')
    BEGIN RAISERROR ('@inputvariable can only contain numbers and commas', 18, 1)
    RETURN
END
```

The above would raise an error whenever the input variable contains a character which is *not* a digit or comma.

Comment: @JB Accepting an answer is an indication to other contributors that the issue has been resolved ... AND ... a little "thank you" acknowledging Tim's time and talent.